# Flutter: Images missing when build

Tags: android, flutter, build, widget, assets

i've got a problem with my flutter project. I've added some images, sounds and a json file to pubspec.yaml like this:

```
 flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/audio/
```

The json is in assets/, the background and some icons in assets/images/.
When running `flutter run` everything works fine. When running `flutter build` and install the apk on device, the background is available, the icons are not.

Example output:

```
I/flutter (20572): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/background.png")                  
I/flutter (20572): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#16f51(), name:                       
I/flutter (20572):   "assets/images/background.png", scale: 1.0)                                                   
I/flutter (20572): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (20572): Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/images/Soundboard Max.png
```

My implementation looks like this:

```
class SoundboardGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  SoundboardGrid({
    Key key,
    @required this.sounds,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Sound> sounds;
  final Player audioPlayer = Player();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/background.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: GridView.count(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        childAspectRatio: 0.8,
        children: List.generate(
          sounds.length,
          (index) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      audioPlayer.play(sounds[index].filename);
                    },
                                      child: Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 3),
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/Soundboard ${sounds[index].speaker}.png')
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    sounds[index].filename,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 11),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using the Imageprovider instead of the "Image.asset Widget" gives the same result.

Comment: Do all the missing icon files contain a space in their name? If so, can you remove or replace it with an underscore, for example, and try again?

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try importing individual assets in the pubspec.yaml file. This may work. 
Put this in assets file below other assets.

```
- assets/images/Soundboard Max.png
```

This solution may work.